# Load more function in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iphone, ajax

**EDIT:** This question was initially too general, I think. So What I really need is a very good tutorial on how to implement the Load More function on Safari for **iPhone** just like the *Twitter website*(mobile.twitter.com) does. Just a wordpress plugin won't really help. But if the plugin is well explained, like if it is wptouch, home(that also has this function) that can also do.

*I know that it doesn't really matter that it is being displayed on a mobile device, but the point I am stressing is that if such a function is well explained, then it will be up to me to know how to customize it to suit me.*

I am using a javascript function to load entries that come from the database dynamically, so that content opens in the same page (like with twitter(tweets feed) and facebook(news feed)).

The php/html version(That opens a page in a new tab) is

```
echo '<a href="http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'.$domain_page.'?form='.$form_id.'&page='.($page+1).'">Load more entries&rsaquo; </a>';
```

The javascript/ajax version:

```
<div id="call_hv<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" class="ajax-load-more">

                <img id="spinner<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" class="spin" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/main-ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none" alt="" /> 

                <a class="ajax" href="javascript:$ajax_hv('#spinner<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>').fadeIn(200); 

                $ajax_hv('#ajaxentries_hv<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>').load('form='<? echo $form_id; ?>&page=<?php echo $page+1;?>', {}, 

                function(){ $ajax_hv('#call_hv<?php echo md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>').fadeOut();})">Load more entries... 

                </a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic idea is to listen to scroll events, and implement paging on the server side.

A `scroll` event is fired whenever the document or a contained HTML element scrolls. I'll use this sketch for reference keeping the following things in mind:

Let's say the height of the browser window is 800px, and the initial height of the content is 2500px. The threshold for loading AJAX content is when the user scrolls to the bottom 100px of our content (after the first 2400px).

[image]

We will need to keep track of the following 2 items:

1. Items/Pages loaded so far.
2. How far are we from the bottom of
   the page.

The code references are in MooTools, but the concept is the same. Converting it to jQuery is a trivial task once you understand it.

```
var maxPage = 1;
var threshold = 100;
```

We need to know whenever the page scrolls, so add a handler for [scroll events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll). Find the scroll distance to the bottom of the page. If it's less than the defined threshold (100px), then fire off an AJAX request loading the next page. When the response comes (if successful), append it to the page and increment maxPage number.

Another thing to keep in mind is to only fire an AJAX request if content is not already being loaded. Have a flag that indicates whether the page request is still pending.

`var isLoading = false;`

```
window.addEvent('scroll', function() {
    // the height of the entire content (including overflow)
    var contentHeight = window.getScrollSize().y;
    // current scroll is height of content that's above the viewport plus
    // height of the viewport.
    var contentScrolled = window.getScroll().y + window.getSize().y;
    var distanceToBottom = contentHeight - contentScrolled;
    var closeToBottomOfPage = distanceToBottom < threshold;
    var shouldLoadMoreContent = !isLoading && closeToBottomOfPage;

    if(shouldLoadMoreContent) {
        // create an ajax request
        var request = new Request({
            url: 'http://www.example.com/more',
            onSuccess: function(responseText) {
                $('page').append(responseText);
                maxPage++;
            },
            onRequest: function() {
                isLoading = true;
            },
            onComplete: function() {
                isLoading = false;
            }
        });
        // fire off ajax request with the page # as a querystring param
        request.send({page: maxPage});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I am digesting this and testing :)

Answer (score 1):

Commonly called an Infinite scroll. There are plugins for jQuery and Wordpress:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: Any other link that explains the workings of the function rather than just giving a jQuery plugin?